# Animate SVG property such as fill color without third-party library

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

How can I make the fill color of an SVG `circle` animate once from a given start (opaque black) to a given end (transparent/none). This should be triggered by a JavaScript function and the animation is a one-shot lasting a few hundred milliseconds. How can I do this with DOM/CSS without having to draw in a third-party library such as Snap.svg?

So when my callback is invoked

- set immediately `fill: black`
- transition over period of 200ms to `fill: none`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `<animate>` function. Here's a [demo](http://alkhoo-app.appspot.com/akfiddle/circle_animate_onlyJS.html) that doesn't have external library.

You can trigger the animation from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455773/svg-trigger-animation-with-event)

Comment: Thanks for putting up the demo!

Answer (score 1):

Using pure JS you can achieve this. This thread has a function that will do what you're asking for:
 [Animate without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17361309/4946307).

The function takes the element, the attribute to animate, and the speed in ms to perform the animation. In your case something like this would be appropriate `animate(circle, fill, 300)`.  You'll likely have to alter it a bit to adapt to the alpha value decreasing, but this is the idea.