# svg animation works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I am trying to animate an svg-circle. It works fine the first time a press the button, but not the next time. Any ide of what could be the problem?

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    console.log('Button click');
    currentBallCircle = $("#currentBallCircle");
    currentBallCircle.animate({
      cx: "200", // New x-coordinate
    }, {
      duration: 1000,
      start: function() {
        console.log('Animation start');
        $(this).attr("cx", "100");
      },
      complete: function() {
        console.log('Animation completed!');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Start Animation</button>
<svg height="200">
  <circle id="currentBallCircle" r="30" cy="50" stroke-width="2" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The output to the console is showing every time: Click, start and completed as expected.

Comment: `animate({ cx: "200" }` will manipulate the inline style of the element, when you check it in DOM inspector afterwards, you will see `style="cx: 200px;"` on there. `$(this).attr("cx", "100");` is not manipulating CSS, it is setting a `cx` attribute on the element. (Although I could not get it to work with any attempt to set the cx _style_ instead either - but i am guessing that might be due to how `.animate` works. If I manipulate the inline style directly using browser dev tools, then it will animate again on the next click.)

Comment: See [jquery animation of specific attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670718/jquery-animation-of-specific-attributes)

Comment: or you can insert a `.css('cx','')` before the `animate` keyword to reset it. Like this`currentBallCircle.css('cx','').animate(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for answers.
I tried out the trick Gabriele showed by clearing the css before animation. Now, the animation triggers every time. However, the first animation starts from cx=0, instead of cx=100 like the next triggers does.

Comment: The attribute is ignored because the style property `cx` added by the animation function has a higher specificity than the `cx` attribute and overrides this value.  But why don't you add the cx=100 value to the circle element at the beginning?